# Terraform list of tuples as string to iterate in Shell script

Tags: list, tuples, terraform

I have a list of tuples:

```
variable "list_of_tuples" {
  type = list(tuple([string, string]))
}
```

and data for that will look something like this: `(["c", "3"], ["e", "5"])`

My aim is to convert the list to a string like `"c 3, e 5"` so I can use it in my template Bash script file to iterate in the similar way a here:

```sh
for i in "c 3" "e 5"
do
    set -- $i
    echo $1 and $2
done
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example of the output you want seems to disagree with the larger bash example you shared: there's no comma in the bash example and the individual items are in quotes. I'm going to answer for what you showed in the full bash example, but you could also use the same principles as in this example to produce the comma-separated form.

```
join(" ", [for pair in var.list_of_tuples : "\"${join(" ", pair)}\""])
```

The innermost `join(" ", pair)` transforms e.g. `["c", "3"]` into `"c 3"`, the [`for` expression](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions.html#for-expressions) wraps each one in literal quotes like `"\"c 3\""` and then finally the outer join concatenates them all together to produce the `"\"c 3\" \"e 5\""` you need. You can then interpolate that into the bash script:

```
locals {
  bash_script = <<-EOT
    for i in ${join(" ", [for pair in var.list_of_tuples : "\"${join(" ", pair)}\""])}
    do
      set -- $i
      echo $1 and $2
    done
  EOT
}
```